# Laravel 5.2.29 $errors problem

Tags: php, laravel

Я использую Laravel v-5.2.29. Мой роутинг выглядит следующим образом

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'], function () {
    Route::controller('auth'   , 'Auth\AuthController');
});
```

А в контроллере я тоже правильно передаю валидацию

```
return back()->withErrors('Some error message');
```

Когда какие нибудь поля не проходят валидацию то по идее `$errors` должен присутствовать в view.

Но он у меня всегда пустой. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему, может в версии она?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ларавеле 5.2 роуты не нужно явно вносить в группу `web` они туда попадают по умолчанию (как можно посмотреть в `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`)

тоесть достатчно

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'], function () {
    Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController');
});
```

Заменить на

```
Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController');
```

Comment: Да спасибо ,просто надо посмотреть в какой версии как обустроено.